# How to use masked array as index in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, when i want to use numpy masked array as index, i got some trouble:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
b=np.array([[0,1],[3,5]])
>>> a[b]
   array([[0, 1],
          [3, 5]]
```

well, THE PROBLEM is number 3 in b is not what i want. The result i want to geti is like

```
a[b]=array([[0, 1],
              [5]])
```

so i used the numpy.ma:

```
b=np.ma.masked_equal(b,3)
>>> b
masked_array(data =
 [[0 1]
  [-- 5]],
         mask =
 [[False False]
 [ True False]],
   fill_value = 3)
>>> a[b]
array([[0, 1],
   [3, 5]])
```

As we can see, the masked value still works as index, is there a way to fix it ？

Comment: What does 'ignore it' mean, in this context?  In general masked arrays only work with masked array functions and methods.  They aren't a drop in substitute for regular arrays.  But, with more information we can suggest ways to use it, or something equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> np.ma.masked_array(a[b.data], b.mask)
masked_array(data =
 [[0 1]
 [-- 5]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [ True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.